# basemap plot only region of interest, not entire globe

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I need to use a mollweide projection but plot only a region of interest. (eg lat=[10,90], lon=[-25, 45]). Basic code below.

It seems this does not possible with some projections in Basemap
(http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap).

Maybe final plot can be masked with polygons. But maybe there's a cleaner way?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='moll',lon_0=0, lat_0=0,
        llcrnrlon = -25.0, llcrnrlat = 10.0,
        urcrnrlon = 45.0, urcrnrlat = 90.0)

# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10.0, 91.0, 5.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-25.0, 46.0, 5.))

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the axes and set the limit with plain matplotlib:

```
ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim(-25,45)
ax.set_ylim(10,90)
```

Comment: I tried your code at different places but parallels+meridians still draw outside the region of interest. And the globe outline still plots. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right and that as of version 1.0.7, the projections indicated as "global" in [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapsetup.html) are not offering sub-setting.